# Blazor and WebApi in same solution: Why is the POST response 405: Method not allowed?

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api, crud, blazor-webassembly

I've got two Project in one solution:

- WebApi
- Blazor wasm

I start both projects with

In **Program.cs** is an external HttpClient added

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WEbApi", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:12639"));
```

The Sender from my Index.razor.cs

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

    public partial class Index
    {
        [Inject] private IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory { get; set; }

        public void Send()
        {
            var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("WEbApi");

            var res = client.PostAsJsonAsync("order","FOO");
        }

    }
```

In the WEbApi Project the received controller code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Ok("GET done");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExecuteOrder([FromBody] string order)
        {
            
            return Ok("POST done");
        }
    }
```

The GET request return OK.

The Problem:
client.PutAsJsonAsync("order","FOO") response a 405: method not allowed (listened via wireshark).

I try a POST with Postman, and it works!

Comment: I can't see any method that handles HttpPut in your controller. Try using client.PostAsJsonAsync.

Comment: @ThomasErdösi thank you for answer.
I edit my code to "PostAsJsonAsync". The PutAsJsonAsync was from a Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to configure CORS in tzh WebApi project. Now it works.

Insert this code in the **public void Configure()** in the **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCors(cors => cors
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                .AllowCredentials()
            );
```